# Porque me da error Undefined index: PHP

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un formulario y en el login no se porque me da error en las lineas 2 y 3 de aquí en el `if ($result->num_rows > 0)` , y no lo entiendo, alguien me puede ayudar?

> Undefined index: user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\prova\Untis\sigin.php on
>   line 32
>
> Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\prova\Untis\sigin.php on
>   line 33

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 $user = test_input($_POST["user_id"]);
$pass = test_input($_POST["password"]);

$sql2 = "SELECT id_user FROM users WHERE id_user like '$user'"; //Define a variable of a query
$result = $conn->query($sql2);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $userbd = $row["user_id"];
    $passbd = $row["password"];
}
}

if (empty($user)) {
$userError = true;
    $valid = false;
} elseif ($user != $userbd){
$uservalid = true;
    $valid = false;}

if (empty($pass)) {
$passError = true;
    $valid = false;
} elseif ($pass != password_verify($pass, $passbd)) {
$valid = false;
    $passvalid = true;}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el formulario (HTML). Para que lleguen los datos los `input` deberían tener `name="user_id"` y `name="password"`

Comment: Además de lo que te dice @A.Cedano, prueba a cambiar en el while, el nombre de la columna 'user_id' por 'id_user', que es el nombre que veo en el Select y cuenta que ocurre.

Comment: tu consulta solo devuelve id_user, y luego intentas leer el parametro user_id. Ademas, intentas leer otro parametro que NO devuelves en el select de la consulta...

Comment: Correcto @Jakala le falta indicar en el select la contraseña. Quería asegurarme que con el cambio de user_id por id_user, le disminuían los errores antes de dar una respuesta, porque creo que el problema está primero en el select y despues en la forma de llamar a las columnas en el while

Comment: He cambiado el "user_id" por "id_user" i me aparece el mismo error

Comment: Miquelp, deberías compartir en tu pregunta el código HTML del formulario que estás enviando al PHP. El error está probablemente allí y no en PHP.

Comment: @Miquelp haz primero lo que te ha pedido A.Cedano en el primer comentario porque de lo contrario vamos tanteando a ciegas

Comment: Sin entrar a fondo a valorar el código y sin ver el formulario que envías... revisa que esas variables existen en la request POST que envías.

Comment: Voto el cierre de la pregunta por no poder reproducirse el problema sin el código HTML del formulario.